# PhP Mysql how to use include properly, avoid headers error

Tags: php, mysql, html, include

Yo bros.  I am writing a followup question to this post here:  [Understanding cache limiter | headers already sent php warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254817/understanding-cache-limiter-headers-already-sent-php-warning) 
Again I'm relatively new but I'm following relatively well, this has me stumped however.

Problem notes:

- I am using Xara Pro 9 to export a page
- Inside are nested php scripts, used to post various info all over the page
- I get "Headers already sent" warnings because of the php's are located deep in the code
- Additionally if I try to add additional.php scripts It usually ends up not showing up or breaking the previous script.

So breaking this down, Xara exports index_3.html (which I change to index_3.php so it can parse.)  The beginning of the Xara document looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252"/>
 <meta name="Generator" content="Xara HTML filter v.6.0.1.335"/>
 <meta name="XAR Files" content="index_htm_files/xr_files.txt"/>
 <title>index_3</title>  etc....
```

And I've learned it's already too late to include php because  is output.  Xara uses html placeholders in the wysiwyg editor. Then in the actual index_3.html(php) code, the php includes later way down in the document using  like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 47px; top: 39px; width: 503px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="width: 503px;  height:  256px;  overflow:  auto;">
<?php include 'get_opwire.php'; ?>
</div>
 </div>
```

(As for why it doubles up on the div I have no idea)... anyway, that get_opwire.php *will* display a table like it's suppose to, but it throws those header warnings.  Then additionally, further down in index_3, there is another php..

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 533px; width: 100px; height: 26px;">
<div style="width: 100px;  height:  26px;">
<?php include 'usernameget.php'; ?>
</div>
 </div>
```

usernameget.php refuses to display, UNLESS I get rid of opwire, as if xara only wants to handle 1 php inclusion.

So, to fix the warnings, I've been given 3 options in the previous question

```
1.) Have separate files. You would have a file like page_start.php that does includes and session_start that you include at the very
top of index_3.php, and a file like display_table.php that displays
your table that you include where the table goes.

2.) Turn the table into a function. You would wrap the table output inside a function, include get_opwire.php at the very top of
index_3.php, then call the function down where you want the table.

3.) Use output buffering. Output buffering catches the stuff printed out so that you can use it later. It would go like this:
```

I have experimented with all three of these for a day now especially option 3, but I'm just to new to php to put it together. I'd also like to logically understand why the second php include fails and to know what my actual best option is. Help would be very much appreciated!

Edit: Errors:

```
[08-Oct-2013 11:36:09] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home2/mysite/public_html/mysubsite/index_3.php:7) in /home2/mysite/public_html/mysubsite/functions.php on line 12

[08-Oct-2013 11:36:09] PHP Warning:  session_regenerate_id() [<a href='function.session-regenerate-id'>function.session-regenerate-id</a>]: Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent in /home2/mysite/public_html/mysubsite/functions.php on line 13
```

Comment: Please post the actual errors you are receiving from the script. If it's complaining about starting a session after headers have already been sent, put the session_start at the top of the index file/main file, and not in the included files.

Comment: Actual errors edited in

Comment: It appears that when I put the includes at the top of the index_3.php, it loads as a white page, none of the graphics or php tables

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` and any other session-manipulation (creating session ID, moving the session folder) must be done before any output is sent to the browser. Try putting it as the very first lines of the index/main file, and make sure it is NOT in any other file.

Comment: When I attempt that, loading the file no longer works, it just displays a white page and no new logged errors...

Comment: Odd that it would do that. There should be some errors somewhere.

Comment: I would share the entirety of my code publicly to get this solved but it's rather in depth. Thoughts?