# html / php include display issue, one cancels the other

Tags: php, html, include

Simply put:

```
 <div style="position: absolute; left: 47px; top: 39px; width: 503px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="width: 503px;  height:  256px;  overflow:  auto;">
<?php include 'get_opwire.php'; ?>
</div>
 </div>
 <div style="position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 533px; width: 100px; height: 26px;">
<div style="width: 100px;  height:  26px;">
<?php include 'usernameget.php'; ?>
</div>
 </div>
```

this will display get_opwire.php but not usernameget.php

and when I switch them....

```
 <div style="position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 533px; width: 100px; height: 26px;">
<div style="width: 100px;  height:  26px;">
<?php include 'usernameget.php'; ?>
</div>
 </div>
 <div style="position: absolute; left: 47px; top: 39px; width: 503px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="width: 503px;  height:  256px;  overflow:  auto;">
<?php include 'get_opwire.php'; ?>
</div>
 </div>
```

this will display usernameget.php but not get_opwire.php

Can anyone tell me why this is/how to display both?
(this file is mostly html, and renamed to .php to parse a few includes like above)
In case your wondering, the nested divs result from Xara 9's html placeholder system.  The display problem remains when I clean them up to one  each.

Comment: Are any errors thrown in your error log? Something in the included files might cancel out something in the other.

Comment: An error or exception thrown inside get_opwire.php?

Comment: The errors I'm getting are header related.  I wrote out that issue here but got no response:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306912/php-mysql-how-to-use-include-properly-avoid-headers-error

Comment: Commented on that post

Comment: Check for inclusion rightness with `if((include 'file.php') == 'OK') echo "OK";`. There might be problems with your files.

Comment: op_wire.php and usernameget.php on their own seem to be working fine, no errors populating in the log.

Comment: What does the resulting HTML source look like? Is the place where the second file would have been included simply empty? Or are there other errors?

Comment: It's simply empty in the place where the second php should show up.  It's so strange!